# How does the calculator code works by putting numbers (values) in a string format

Tags: javascript

I tried to code calculator in java script and i need to put the button values in between a single quote (like a string format). How come strings work with operators to give the required result.

This is a portion of the working code

```
<button onclick="
        calculation += '1';
        console.log(calculation);
      ">1</button>
      
      <button onclick="
        calculation += '2';
        console.log(calculation);
      ">2</button>
```

My question is why the values are put between quote like a string format?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. *between ticks like a string* means absolutely nothing to me... what are "ticks" in this context?

Comment: @freefaller I think the OP means the single quote.  As in why is it ```'1'``` and not ```1```

Comment: @ewokx - ah, ok, makes sense - not heard that terminology before

Comment: `This is a portion of the working code` Please provide all the relevant code, as it's not at all clear what you're asking.

Comment: I can only guess, that these buttons are not supposed to perform an actual calculation, but are supposed to append new digits to a string value? Then the purpose of this would probably be to make sure that string concatenation is performed, and not mathematical addition after possible type conversion.

Comment: @freefaller ... you get my question. I think numbers are the working values in a simple calculator than a string or other type of data.

Comment: @kalkidan - are you asking why `calculation + '1'` works but `calculation + 1` doesn't?  If so, are you aware of "string concatenation"?  If you have `1 + 2` the mathematical result is `3`... but if you have `'1' + '2'` the string concatenation is `'12'`.  If you need `calculation` to be an actual value, then each time you press the button you would need something like `calculation = (calculation * 10) + 1`

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you're asking why `calculation + '1'` works, but `calculation + 1` doesnt.

If that is the case, you need to be aware of something called [string concatenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation).

When you add two numerical values together, you get the mathematical result (e.g. `1 + 2 = 3`).

But if you "add" two string values together, you get the concatenation of those strings (e.g. `'1' + '2' = '12'`).

So for your calculator, when you press the buttons it is the string concatenation that is doing the work for you.

However, be aware that the `calculation` variable is a string, not a number.

So you would then need to look at [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to convert that string back to a number.

---

Alternatively, if you wanted `calculation` to be a numeric variable, then you would need to first "move" your existing number up a place before adding the new value (e.g. `calculation = (calculation * 10) + 1`